# Spring boot 2.1 / java 11 app not recognizing accentuated characters after migrating from Spring boot 2.0.5 / java 8

Tags: java, spring-boot, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters, java-11

I have a Spring boot web app that used to work perfectly fine on java 8 and Spring boot 2.0.5.  Now, when i visit any page and try to input data that has a É character for example, the character is saved as ? in the database and obviously retrieved as such.  I have changed 0 code aside from adding the javax.json.bind-api dependency that is no longer built into the JRE.  Is there some sort of global character encoding property that needs to be changed for non-standard characters to be recognized properly?

***EDIT***

This is the relevant bit of my JSP page :

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="medClass" class="form-style-7">
    <form:input path="name" id="name"/>
</form:form>
```

Controller code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/newMedClass"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveMedClass(@Valid MedClass medClass, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) 
{
    boolean hasCustomErrors = validate(result, medClass);
    if ((hasCustomErrors) || (result.hasErrors()))
    {
        setPermissions(model);

        return "medClassDataAccess";
    }
    medClassService.save(medClass);
    session.setAttribute("successMessage", "Successfully added med class \"" + medClass.getName() + "\"!");
    return "redirect:/medClasses/list";
}
```

When entering ÉÉÉÉ as the name for this entity (yes it's a string), the entity comes into the controller with ???? already and is therefore saved as such.

***EDIT***

I have this line at the top of every JSP :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
```

Does this need to be changed?

Thanks

Comment: Is that character a part of a string or maybe a property file? Just speculating based on the restricted information this [might be because of the UTF-8 default encoding now.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/intl/internationalization-enhancements-jdk-9.htm#JSINT-GUID-974CF488-23E8-4963-A322-82006A7A14C7)

Comment: The issue is with the actual data entered by the user, which is saved as entities into a MSSQL database using Hibernate.

Comment: how is it read by your application? as a string?

Comment: please see my edits for clarifications and code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the JSPs' charset to UTF-8 fixed it.  How this worked perfectly before is a complete mystery...

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, would certainly be useful for future readers :)

Comment: I hope so!  This is very strange, like i said everything worked perfectly with Spring Boot 2.0.5 and java 8 and those lines contained ISO-8859-1 in all of my 60+ JSP pages.